# How do I create a fallible version of include_str?

Tags: rust, macros

[`include_str!("file")`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html) fails at compile time if the requested file does not exist. I am looking for a macro which instead returns `None` in this case: `try_include_str!("file") -> Option<&'static str>`.

This would be fairly straightforward if I could check whether a file exists at compile time but from what I looked there is no macro exposed for this in `std`.
How else could I implement this?

Comment: I don't think that sound right, you probably having a xy problem.

Comment: You might be able to use a build script for this. I haven't used them but cargo supports running a build script out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using [`include_dir`](https://crates.io/crates/include_dir) since it lets you check if a path exists in the included directory.

Disadvantage: it will include all the files in a directory, which might include files you're not planning to access at all, increasing the binary size. But if you can arrange so only the files you care about are in a certain directory, whether or not they exist, then it should do well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [include_optional](https://crates.io/crates/include_optional) crate that does this, but it hasn't been updated in a while.